# Find all combinations of advanced filter criteria

Tags: vba, excel, filter, permutation

I've searched extensively and found plenty of information on permutations, but I can't think of a good way to adapt them. Its frustrating because I don't think the answer is that hard but I can't seem to get there on my own.

I am trying to convert a range of cells containing Selection Criteria into a range that Advanced Filter can read.  The range of selection criteria looks like this:

[image: Raw Selection Criteria]

The problem is, Advanced Filter is evaluating each row as a separate filter set.  The logic looks something like this:

```
[awake AND bob AND cat AND earth AND yes] OR [sleeping AND sally AND dog AND earth AND yes] OR ... OR [martha].
```

This is the way Advanced Filter is supposed to work, but I need it to work like autofilter where I'd go through each field and check each filter criteria.  The logic should look like this:

```
[awake OR sleeping] AND [bob OR sally OR george OR martha] AND [cat OR dog OR bird] AND [earth] AND [alive]
```

After reading the documentation and multiple forums, the only way to do this I can find is to generate on separate rows every combination of the selection criteria possible.  The new range of selection criteria should look like this:

[image: Working Selection Criteria]

I've tested this by manually setting up the selection criteria range and it works properly, but I cannot figure out the code to automate it.  Here's what I've done so far - it starts off ok but soon starts repeating and missing certain permutations:

```
   If UBound(numRows) > 1 Then

    With Worksheets("fltr")
        .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, UBound(numRows))).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("afltr").Range("A1")
    End With

    'Determine number of rows needed for Advanced filter
    numPermute = numRows(1)
    For dstCol = 2 To UBound(numRows)
        numPermute = numPermute * numRows(dstCol)
    Next dstCol

    'Copy all permutations to advanced filter
    For dstCol = 1 To UBound(numRows)
        If thisRow > numRows(dstCol) Then
        thisRow = 2
        For thisGrp = 1 To numRows(dstCol)
            andSpltPos = 1
            For numRepeat = 1 To numPermute / numRows(dstCol)
                sbstFltrItms = Worksheets("fltr").Cells(4 + thisGrp, dstCol).Value 'MOD Problem?
                Worksheets("afltr").Cells(thisRow, dstCol).Value = sbstFltrItms
                thisRow = thisRow + 1
            Next numRepeat
        Next thisGrp
    Next dstCol

End If
```

Would really appreciate some help either generating the correct permutations or making the Advanced Filter work some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. I put the sheet in "show formula" mode (Ctrl+~) so you can see the formulas...
List to filter is in A7:B14, criteria range is A3:B4.

[image]

After applying the filter I just get one row ("B", "val2").

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks Tim!